# Solution to visualize and compare change over time across categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

Does anyone know what is generally the best practice to visualize data that shows growth for different categories over time?

In my example think of "Category" as a product, the "Type" as the model and the values as a performance metric. I want to visualize the data in a way that would let me prioritize which "Category" and corresponding "Type" have had the most increase in the mean value.

The challenge I'm having is that after I've summarized tabular data to show change over time, the best thing that I can come up with to compare and visualize the summarized data is to show the changing mean for each separate category in it's own excel tab.

There has to be a better way to do this!

I've done a 3d column chart in matplotlib - one row for each category, but it's not effective enough.

It's possible that someone knows the best solution from experience.

Right now the mean values are being shown over time, grouped by "Category" and "Type" in my example.

Maybe I shouldn't be looking at this as a pandas table or matplotlib bar chart at all.

If my goal was to identify and prioritize the 'Category' and it's respective 'Type' where the mean growth has been the most promising, how should I do that?

I really appreciate any help or advice.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import stats
import warnings;warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def calc_slope(row):
    mask = row.notnull()
    a = scipy.stats.linregress(row[mask.values], y=axisvalues[mask])
    return pd.Series(a._asdict())


table=pd.DataFrame({'Category':['A','A','A','B','C','C','C','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','D','A','B','B','A','C','B','B','C','A','A','C','B','B','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'],
                    'Type':['I','I','I','III','II','II','II','III','III','I','I','I','III','III','II','I','III','III','I','II','III','I','II','III','I','II','III','I','II','II','II','II','II','II','II'],
                    'Quarter':['2016-Q1','2017-Q2','2017-Q3','2017-Q4','2017-Q2','2016-Q2','2017-Q2','2016-Q3','2016-Q4','2016-Q2','2016-Q3','2017-Q4','2016-Q1',\
                              '2016-Q2','2016-Q4','2016-Q4','2017-Q2','2017-Q3','2016-Q3','2016-Q4','2016-Q2','2017-Q2','2016-Q1','2017-Q4','2016-Q4','2017-Q2',\
                              '2016-Q1','2017-Q2','2016-Q1','2017-Q2','2016-Q4','2016-Q1','2017-Q2','2017-Q3','2017-Q4'],
                    'Value':np.random.randint(100,1000,size=35)})

db=(table.groupby(['Category','Type','Quarter']).filter(lambda group: len(group) >= 1)).groupby(['Category','Type','Quarter'])["Value"].mean()

db=db.unstack()

axisvalues= np.arange(1,len(db.columns)+1) #used in calc_slope function
db = db.join(db.apply(calc_slope,axis=1))

print(db)
```

Comment: Would a simple vector graph for each category over time not show the increase or decrease of value? And will then presenting the four graphs next to each other not show the differences? Supplemented with a graph of all the categories for scale perhaps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of problem you should really consider [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html).

```
import seaborn as sns

# reshape the data into 'tidy form' for seaborn
melted = pd.melt(db.reset_index(), 
        value_vars=[c for c in db.columns if '-Q' in c],
        value_name='Mean',
        var_name='Quarter',
        id_vars=['Type', 'Category'])

g = sns.factorplot(data=melted, x='Quarter', y='Mean', 
                   col='Type', hue='Category', kind='point')
```

You can change what type of plot you have and explore around really fast and easily. For example:

[image]

And change the 'kind' keyword:

[image]

[edited because its 2:30 am] Maybe fit a trend to the means?

Comment: Thank you. Quick question: Would you consider transforming the data to a 3D cluster type structure to identify areas where the metrics are optimal? I want to make sure I'm finding the best way to do this. Because the way it is now, I would have to cycle through the Categories and eyeball the slopes and lines. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. One thing is you could do line plots (not needed but the visualization usually helps), and calculate a regression on each category/type combination. Then you can follow the regression into the future and see which will be most promising. Without seeing your data though, I can't recommend this since I don't know if it will actually be linear. (It's quite important to use a model which is consistent with your data, but that's a pretty big topic)